# What does JGDownloadAcceleration class used to accelerate download and does it is as good as NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, download

I have used "JGDownloadAcceleration" for multipart download and also accelerate the download speed.

From [JGDownloadAcceleration](https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGDownloadAcceleration)

Does it supports background download and also pause and resume of downloads?

**UPDATE**

I have used below code to start download for any valid URL

```
-(void)addFinalyDownloadTask:(NSString*)fileName andFilePath :(NSString*)filePath andDestinationPath:(NSString*)fileDestination
{
    NSString *file = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file])
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"This file is already downloading." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        return;
    }

    if (!self.ArrayDownloading)
    {
        self.ArrayDownloading=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *dictInfo=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dictInfo setObject:fileName forKey:kDownloadKeyFileName];
    [dictInfo setObject:fileDestination forKey:kDownloadKeyFilePath];
    [dictInfo setObject:[self getCurrentFolderName:fileDestination] forKey:kDownloadKeyFolderName];
    [dictInfo setObject:filePath forKey:kDownloadKeyURL];
    [dictInfo setObject:@"0" forKey:kDownloadKeyProgress];
    [dictInfo setObject:@"In Queue" forKey:kDownloadKeyDetails];
    [dictInfo setObject:RequestStatusDownloading forKey:kDownloadKeyStatus];
    [self.ArrayDownloading addObject:dictInfo];

    NSMutableArray *arrayDownloding = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:DOWNLOAD_OBJ] mutableCopy];
    if (arrayDownloding==nil)
    {
        arrayDownloding=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    [arrayDownloding addObject:dictInfo];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayDownloding forKey:DOWNLOAD_OBJ];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [self addDownloadTask:fileName andFilePath:filePath andFileDestPath:fileDestination];
    [self.tblDownloading reloadData];
    [self updateDownloadingTabBadge];
}


-(void)addDownloadTask:(NSString *)fileName andFilePath:(NSString*)filePath andFileDestPath:(NSString*)fileDestPath
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //go back to the main thread (not necessary)
        NSString *file = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSLog(@"URL :%@", filePath);

        BOOL resume = YES;

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];

        //customize the request if needed... Example:
        [request setTimeoutInterval:90.0];


        //start downloading the  video to the temporary directory
        JGDownloadOperation *operation = [[JGDownloadOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request destinationPath:file allowResume:resume];
        operation.name=fileDestPath;
        [operation setMaximumNumberOfConnections:6];
        [operation setRetryCount:3];

        __block CFTimeInterval started;

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(JGDownloadOperation *operation)
         {
             double kbLength = (double)operation.contentLength/1024.0f;
             CFTimeInterval delta = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()-started;
             NSLog(@"Success! Downloading %.2f MB took %.1f seconds, average Speed: %.2f kb/s", kbLength/1024.0f, delta, kbLength/delta);

             NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileName == %@",[operation.destinationPath lastPathComponent]];
             NSArray *arrayFilter=[[self.ArrayDownloading filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] mutableCopy];
             NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

             if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:kDownloadKeyFilePath]])
             {
                 [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:kDownloadKeyFilePath] error:NULL];
             }
             unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:operation.destinationPath error:nil] fileSize];
             NSNumber *number=[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:kDownloadKeyFileSize];

             unsigned long long DictfileSize =[number unsignedLongLongValue];

             if (fileSize==DictfileSize)
             {
                 BOOL isWrite = [fileManager moveItemAtPath:operation.destinationPath toPath:[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:kDownloadKeyFilePath] error:NULL];

                 if (isWrite)
                 {
                     NSInteger index = [self.ArrayDownloading indexOfObject:[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0]];

                     [self.ArrayDownloading removeObjectAtIndex:index];
                     NSMutableArray *arrayDownloding=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:DOWNLOAD_OBJ] mutableCopy];
                     NSArray *ArrayFilter=[arrayDownloding filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

                     if (ArrayFilter.count>0)
                     {
                         [arrayDownloding removeObject:[ArrayFilter objectAtIndex:0]];
                         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayDownloding forKey:DOWNLOAD_OBJ];
                         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                     }

                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         [self presentNotificationForDownload];
                         [self updateDownloadingTabBadge];
                         [self.tblDownloading reloadData];
                     });
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Can`t Write File At Path." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                     });
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     UIAlertController *actionControllerDelete =   [UIAlertController
                                                                    alertControllerWithTitle:@"Options"
                                                                    message:@"The File Was currupted."
                                                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                     UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                                          actionWithTitle:@"Retry"
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                          {
                                              NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
                                              [self addDownloadTask:[dict valueForKey:kDownloadKeyFileName] andFilePath:[dict valueForKey:kDownloadKeyURL] andFileDestPath:[dict valueForKey:kDownloadKeyFilePath]];
                                          }];
                     UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                                              actionWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                              {
                                                  [operation cancelAndClearFiles];
                                                  [self.ArrayDownloading removeObject:[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy]];
                                                  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.ArrayDownloading forKey:DOWNLOAD_OBJ];
                                                  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                                                  [self.tblDownloading reloadData];
                                                  [actionControllerDelete dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                              }];

                     [actionControllerDelete addAction:ok];
                     [actionControllerDelete addAction:cancel];
                     [self presentViewController:actionControllerDelete animated:YES completion:nil];
                 });
             }


         }
        failure:^(JGDownloadOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Operation Failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);
             UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
             UIApplicationState appCurrentState = [application applicationState];

             if(appCurrentState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
             {
                 if ([error.localizedDescription isEqualToString:@"The Download was Cancelled"]||[error.localizedDescription isEqualToString:@"The request timed out."]||[error.localizedDescription isEqualToString:@"The network connection was lost."])
                 {
                     NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileName == %@",[operation.destinationPath lastPathComponent]];
                     NSArray *arrayFilter=[[self.ArrayDownloading filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] mutableCopy];
                     NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];

                     [self addDownloadTask:[dict valueForKey:kDownloadKeyFileName] andFilePath:[dict valueForKey:kDownloadKeyURL] andFileDestPath:[dict valueForKey:kDownloadKeyFilePath]];
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                  if ([error.localizedDescription isEqualToString:@"The request timed out."]||[error.localizedDescription isEqualToString:@"The network connection was lost."])
                 {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UltraFast DL" message:@"network connection was lost." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];

                         NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileName == %@",[operation.destinationPath lastPathComponent]];
                         NSArray *arrayFilter=[[self.ArrayDownloading filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] mutableCopy];
                         NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
                         [dict setObject:RequestStatusPaused forKey:kDownloadKeyStatus];
                         NSInteger index =[self.ArrayDownloading indexOfObject:[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0]];
                         [self.ArrayDownloading replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:dict];
                         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.ArrayDownloading forKey:DOWNLOAD_OBJ];
                         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                         [self.tblDownloading reloadData];
                     });
                 }
                 else if ([error.localizedDescription isEqualToString:@"unsupported URL"])
                 {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                         UIAlertController *actionControllerDelete =   [UIAlertController
                                                                        alertControllerWithTitle:@"Options"
                                                                        message:@"The download has been Paused for too long and a connection to the video has been lost."
                                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                         UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                                              actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                              {
                                                  NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileName == %@",[operation.destinationPath lastPathComponent]];
                                                  NSArray *arrayFilter=[[self.ArrayDownloading filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] mutableCopy];
                                                  NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
                                                  [dict setObject:RequestStatusPaused forKey:kDownloadKeyStatus];
                                                  NSInteger index =[self.ArrayDownloading indexOfObject:[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0]];
                                                  [self.ArrayDownloading replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:dict];
                                                  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.ArrayDownloading forKey:DOWNLOAD_OBJ];
                                                  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                                                  [self.tblDownloading reloadData];
                                                  [actionControllerDelete dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                              }];

                         UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                                                  actionWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                  {
                                                      [operation cancelAndClearFiles];
                                                      NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileName == %@",[operation.destinationPath lastPathComponent]];
                                                      NSArray *arrayFilter=[[self.ArrayDownloading filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] mutableCopy];
                                                      [self.ArrayDownloading removeObject:[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy]];
                                                      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.ArrayDownloading forKey:DOWNLOAD_OBJ];
                                                      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                                                      [self.tblDownloading reloadData];
                                                    [actionControllerDelete dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                  }];

                         [actionControllerDelete addAction:ok];
                         [actionControllerDelete addAction:cancel];
                         [self presentViewController:actionControllerDelete animated:YES completion:nil];
                         });
                 }
                 else if (![error.localizedDescription isEqualToString:@"The Download was Cancelled"])
                 {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileName == %@",[operation.destinationPath lastPathComponent]];
                         NSArray *arrayFilter=[[self.ArrayDownloading filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] mutableCopy];
                         NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
                         [dict setObject:RequestStatusPaused forKey:kDownloadKeyStatus];
                         NSInteger index =[self.ArrayDownloading indexOfObject:[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0]];
                         [self.ArrayDownloading replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:dict];
                         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.ArrayDownloading forKey:DOWNLOAD_OBJ];
                         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                         [self.tblDownloading reloadData];
                     });
                 }

             }


         }];

        [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, unsigned long long totalBytesReadThisSession, unsigned long long totalBytesWritten, unsigned long long totalBytesExpectedToRead, NSUInteger tag)
         {
             CFTimeInterval delta = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()-started;
             NSLog(@"Progress: %.2f%% Average Speed: %.2f kB/s Tag:%lu File:%@", ((double)totalBytesWritten/(double)totalBytesExpectedToRead)*100.0f, totalBytesReadThisSession/1024.0f/delta,(unsigned long)tag,fileName);

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fileName == %@",fileName];
                 NSArray *arrayFilter=[[self.ArrayDownloading filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] mutableCopy];

                 if (arrayFilter.count>0)
                 {
                     NSInteger index=[self.ArrayDownloading indexOfObject:[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0]];
                     NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[arrayFilter objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
                     double progress =((double)totalBytesWritten/(double)totalBytesExpectedToRead)*100.0f;
                     double speed=totalBytesReadThisSession/1024.0f/delta;

                     NSString *fileSizeInUnits = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f %@",
                                                  [Utility calculateFileSizeInUnit:(unsigned long long)totalBytesExpectedToRead],
                                                  [Utility calculateUnit:(unsigned long long)totalBytesExpectedToRead]];

                     NSMutableString *detailLabelText=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"(%.1f%@/%@)  Folder:%@",[Utility calculateFileSizeInUnit:(unsigned long long)totalBytesWritten],[Utility calculateUnit:(unsigned long long)totalBytesWritten],fileSizeInUnits,[dict valueForKey:kDownloadKeyFolderName]];

                     [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",detailLabelText] forKey:kDownloadKeyDetails];

                     Cell *cell =(Cell*)[self.tblDownloading cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
                     [cell.progessView setProgress:progress/100];
                     [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.2f%%",progress/100] forKey:kDownloadKeyProgress];
                     [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:totalBytesExpectedToRead] forKeyedSubscript:kDownloadKeyFileSize];

                     [self.ArrayDownloading replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:dict];
                     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.ArrayDownloading forKey:DOWNLOAD_OBJ];
                     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                     NSString *speedDetail=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f kB/s",ceil(speed)];
                     [cell.lblSpeed setText:speedDetail];
                     [cell.lblDetail setText:detailLabelText];
                 }
             });
         }];

        [operation setOperationStartedBlock:^(NSUInteger tag, unsigned long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
        {
            started = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
            NSLog(@"Operation Started, JGDownloadAcceleration version %@", kJGDownloadAccelerationVersion);
        }];

        if (!q)
        {
            q = [[JGOperationQueue alloc] init];
            q.handleNetworkActivityIndicator = YES;
            q.handleBackgroundTask = YES;
        }

        [q addOperation:operation];
    });

}
```

As I tested it, it is working in background as of now but is it fine that this will approved on App Store as it does not use `NSURLSession` for background download and as I know only `NSURLSession` is working fine with background downloading tasks.

Please guide me or point me out in right direction. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your code working .?

Comment: I am using the same lib but its not working .can you help me out.?

Comment: @FaranGhani can you explain what is not working in this lib? or What type of help do you need? will you please provide some more details :)